# where are f:attribute name/value pairs stored?

Tags: jsf

I'm using the following (example)

```
<h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{indexBean.submit}" 
        actionListener="#{indexBean.btnListener}" >
    <f:attribute name="valueOne" value="v1" />
    <f:attribute name="valueTwo" value="v2" />
    <f:attribute name="valueThree" value="v3" />
</h:commandButton>
```

When the page is rendered i'm looking at the source code through the browser, but i cant find the values in some sort of hidden fields or anything else.

Are they stored at the back end on server side, in the view state or some where else?

Best Wishes,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are stored as attribtues of the component in question. They do not end up in the generated HTML output because the component's renderer does not recognize them as standard HTML attributes.

The component is in turn stored in the component tree in the server side memory and if it concerns an `UIForm`, `UIInput` or `UICommand` component, then it's also stored in the view state.

If you want to pass visible parameters, you should rather be using `<f:param>`. They will then be visible in the generated JavaScript `onclick` function of the component's HTML representation. *Note that `<f:param>` in `<h:commandButton>` is only supported since JSF 2.0.*

Comment: As per your "answer" which should actually have been posted as a comment (but you couldn't because you didn't use the same user account), yes you could do that. But you could also just inject the currently logged-in user as a managed bean property so that you don't need to pass it by `f:attribute`.

Comment: I posted my question before I registered!
Everyone deserves a second chance:P
Thanks again!